# Tensorflow pipeline, preprocesing on batches : Beginner issue

Tags: tensorflow, queue, dataset, generator, pipeline

I'm currently trying to implement my first Tensorflow pipeline, and i have many questions about it works even if i've tried to understand the tf documentation. For the moment, my code looks like :

```
import h5py
import tensorflow as tf
sess= tf.InteractiveSession()

batch_size = 10

class generator:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def __call__(self):
        with h5py.File(self.file, 'r') as hf:
            for im in hf["data"]:
                yield tuple(im)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset().from_generator(generator('file.h5'),
                                       output_types= tf.uint8,
                                       output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([6,4,128,128,3])))


dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)

iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
el = iter.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iter.initializer)
    print('batch',sess.run(el).shape)
```

It works well because i obtained what i wanted, that means a array of shape [10,6,4,128,128,3]. But i have no idea about :

- how to apply some preprocessing function on the batch i've selected and not on the whole dataset because my h5 file is about 100 Gigabytes.
- how to shuffle my dataset considering that i can't load the whole dataset in memory
- is this generator structure managing the data queue ? how can i load the data for the next batch at the same time i'm using the previous one in my neural network ? It is automatically done ? Can i define the number of batches i want to have in memory ?

Thanks a lot for any help that can be useful !

Comment: The recommended approach to deal with data too large to fit into memory is to convert it to TFRecord files and read it with [`tf.data.TFRecordDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset) (see [Consuming TFRecord data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_tfrecord_data)). [Here](https://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html) is one tutorial to convert general data into TFRecord files.

Comment: Btw, [support for streaming from HDF5](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3361) has been requested in TensorFlow, but, although it should be technically possible, the response so far has been to use TFRecord files instead.